# How to Delay Postgresql WAL Recycling?

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication

I have 1 primary and 1 replica database (Postgresql 14.5). Most of the time, archives from prod to replica is being transferred with no problem. But rarely it can be interrupted because of network issues. At that time, some wal files can't be sent and when Replica server doesn't find that files since wal files are deleted (probably because of recycling), thus it fails to recover.

How can i delay this deletion of wal files or recycling process in order to prevent desync between primary database and replica? I've checked out some parameters such as "wal_writer_delay" etc but it doesn't seem to be helpful.

Comment: This is what [slots](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION-SLOTS) are for.

Comment: Many Thanks! @jjanes Is it possible to create and activate a slot when replication has already started?